# My DAX code to calculate a moving average is giving an error

Tags: dax

I'm trying to get a moving average on a measure (Booking Average) with the following code but it's giving me an error.  I'm very new to DAX so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
=CALCULATE([Booking Average],
    FILTER(ALL('Range 1'[Number]),
               'Range 1'[Number] <= MAX('Range 1'[Number]) 
                && 'Range 1'[Number]] >= MAX('Range 1'[Number]) - 4
           )
     )
```

Below is the error message.

> This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'The expression is not valid or appears to be incomplete. Please review and correct the expression.
> The syntax for ')' is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like there is some syntax error in the formula itself. Try removing the second square bracket from `'Range 1'[Number]]` and, if it still doesn't work, maybe wrap `>=MAX ('Range 1'[Number]) - 4` into brackets, i.e. -> `>=MAX (('Range 1'[Number]) - 4)`

Comment: Thanks so much!  Removing the bracket worked.  Have a great day!

Comment: I'm glad it worked :-) take care.